# Blender Constraint : Slide Link

Tags: animation, constraints

I am writing this post because after hours of browsing I can't really find what I am looking for... Or maybe  didn't look in the right place...

So I'd like to know how I can simply apply a slide link with a constraint between a tube and a cylinder :
[image: solidworks image]

I have both of my objects on blender but I can't find a way to link them...

Thank you very much for your help !

killian

Answer (score 1):

In my example the bigger cylinder is parent of the small one,and it's rotated 45 degrees on its Y axis. The small one has X and Y loc locked, so it can only slide on its Z local location. The same can be achieved with bones, locking their local attributes.

[image]